# NSString is assigned a value by a method but another method cannot retrieve this value (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, macos

Im currently working on an objective-c program to encode and decode messages. I have an issue with the GUI though. I have an NSString called Sys_Type which stores the setting the system has been set to (Encode or Decode). When I NSLog the NSString in the function that sets its value the correct value is returned however when I call it in the function:

> *-(IBAction)addData:(id)sender*

the value is null. I don't know why this is happening, could some one please help?

I have attached the AppDelegate.h & .m since this is the class that has both functions.

---

**AppDelegate.h**

```c
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    @private

    IBOutlet NSBox *Box;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *Label;
    IBOutlet NSButton *Encode;
    IBOutlet NSButton *Decode;
    NSString *data;

    NSString *Sys_Type;
}

@end
```

---

**AppDelegate.m**

```c
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include "MasterView.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MasterView *masterView;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *textInput_Sheet;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Create the master View
    self.masterView = [[MasterView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterView"    bundle:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (IBAction)Encode:(id)sender {
    Sys_Type = @"ENCODE";

    // Hide system setup
    Box.hidden = true;
    Label.hidden = true;
    Encode.hidden = true;
    Decode.hidden = true;

    // Add the view to the Window's content view
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterView.view];
    self.masterView.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;

    // Set view to encode
    [self.masterView SetType:Sys_Type];

    NSLog(@"Sys: %@",Sys_Type);
}

- (IBAction)Decode:(id)sender {
    Sys_Type = @"DECODE";

    // Hide system setup
    Box.hidden = true;
    Label.hidden = true;
    Encode.enabled = false;
    Encode.hidden = true;
    Decode.enabled = false;
    Decode.hidden = true;

    // Add the view to the Window's content view
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterView.view];
    self.masterView.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;

    // Set view to encode
    [self.masterView SetType:Sys_Type];

    NSLog(@"Sys: %@",Sys_Type);
}

- (void)clearView {

    [self.window.contentView removeView:self.masterView.view];
}

- (IBAction)Reset:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"reset fired");

    // Show system setup
    Box.hidden = false;
    Label.hidden = false;
    Encode.enabled = true;
    Encode.hidden = false;
    Decode.enabled = true;
    Decode.hidden = false;

   // Clear view
   [self clearView]; // This isn't working, this is another issue, but not the main one :)
}

- (IBAction)addData:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button Fired");
    NSLog(@"Sys: %@",Sys_Type);

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Key:                      *
     * 0 - MasterView Data Adder *
     * 1 - Text input ok         *
     * 2 - File input ok         *
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

    if ([Sys isEqualToString:@"ENCODE"]) {
        NSLog(@"Fired");

        // This is where the specific sheet will be loaded


    } else if ([Sys_Type isEqualToString:@"DECODE"]) {

    }
}

- (IBAction)Add_Image:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)Start_Sys:(id)sender {

}

@end
```

Thank you so much in advance :D

Comment: You haven't made it clear.

Comment: (How is the value of Sys_Type supposed to magically jump from AppDelegate to MasterView?)

Comment: Please refer to the "minimal" part of [creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Is there a question here?**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: I hope I have cleared it up now and made it "minimal" enough

Answer (score -1):

in `addData:` you log `Sys` in the other methods `Sys_Type`. Check your variable naming.

Comment: Ah sorry that was a work around I had been trying but failed, I had tried to pass the data by inputing it directly into the method. I have fixed the typo, id there another possibility you see why I keep getting null even though it definitely has been defined a value?